# Page Control Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to figure out how to add a page control to my view correctly.  I have a keypad currently on the view along with a picker, but I want to separate the keypad and picker.

So I want to swipe to page two, and load a different view which essentially just has a picker.  Page one will just have a keypad.

I can't find an example of a page control that switches to two separate views.  I looked at the apple example PageControl, but that did not solve my issues.

Any help, suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: like @Mac said with default keyboard its not possible.. with a custom keypad, you can add both the key pad and picker to a scroll view and switch between them.. page control is very easy to use and how you show your two views does not affect it's implementation

Comment: I'm not finding it too easy at this point, any tutorials, you came across, that might help.  I looked at the apple one already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this with the native keypad - it doesn't belong to any one view, and so cannot be "paged" in the manner you describe.

As for a couple of hints as far as implementing paging: what you'll want to do is make a `UIScrollView`, set it's `contentSize` to be two pages wide (or more if you prefer), and set `pagingEnabled` to `YES`. Then add your pages as subviews. **Note that the `UIPageControl` does not itself implement paging** - it is an *indicator* only.

Some basic sample code (untested) assuming horizontal paging:

```
- (void) initPagesForScrollview:(UIScrollView*) scrollView
{
    CGRect pageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.bounds.size.width,
        scrollView.bounds.size.height);

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageFrame.size.width * 2,
        pageFrame.size.height)
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    UIView* page1 = ...
    page1.frame = pageFrame;
    [scrollView addSubview:page1];

    UIView* page2 = ...
    pageFrame.origin.x += pageFrame.size.width;
    page2.frame = pageFrame;
    [scrollView addSubview:page2];
}
```

Note the origin of page 2 shifted to the right to make it begin off screen.

You can also do most of this through interface builder, but that's a little more difficult to demonstrate here... Feel free to ask if there's something specific you need.

Comment: This is not working for me, if I have two nibs, one for the keypad, and one for the picker, how can I manipulate this for that.  Specifically UIView part, it says it does not have a frame.